# Optim.jl makes many redundant function calls per iteration

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization

Optim.jl does many redundant function calls. For a function of 6 variables and method LBFGS() (with no supplied gradient - my function is the solution to a fixed point problem with no easy to compute gradient and ForwardDiff and ReverseDiff, for some reason, don't work with my code).

It calls the function 39 times in the first iteration. What is more, many of these function calls are evaluated at exactly the same inputs. This seems very inefficient - am I doing something wrong? If not, what are some things I could do to increase efficiency?

My code is currently the following - let me know if you need more to give an answer.

```
function f(x::Vector{Float64})

    modelPar.ρ = x[1]
    modelPar.χI = x[2]
    modelPar.χS = x[3]
    modelPar.χE = x[4] * x[3]
    modelPar.λ = x[5]
    modelPar.ν = x[6]

    f = open("figures/log.txt","a")

    write(f,"Iteration: ρ = $(x[1]); χI = $(x[2]); χS = $(x[3]); 
                        χE = $(x[3] * x[4]); λ = $(x[5]); ν = $(x[6])\n")

    close(f)

    output = computeScore(algoPar,modelPar,guess,targets,weights)

end

initial_x = [ modelPar.ρ;
              modelPar.χI;
              modelPar.χS;
              modelPar.χE / modelPar.χS;
              modelPar.λ;
              modelPar.ν ]

lower = [0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 1.001, 0.01]
upper = [0.1, 6, 6, 0.99, 1.5, 0.5]

inner_optimizer = LBFGS()

results = optimize(f,lower,upper,initial_x,Fminbox(inner_optimizer),
         Optim.Options(iterations = 0, store_trace = true, show_trace = true))
```

The trace is the following

```
Results of Optimization Algorithm
* Algorithm: Fminbox with L-BFGS
* Starting Point: [0.04,4.0,2.0,0.5,1.05,0.05]
* Minimizer: [0.04,4.0,2.0,0.5,1.05,0.05]
* Minimum: 2.069848e-02
* Iterations: 1
* Convergence: true
  * |x - x'| ≤ 0.0e+00: true 
    |x - x'| = 0.00e+00 
  * |f(x) - f(x')| ≤ 0.0e+00 |f(x)|: true
    |f(x) - f(x')| = 0.00e+00 |f(x)|
  * |g(x)| ≤ 1.0e-08: false 
    |g(x)| = 1.63e-01 
  * Stopped by an increasing objective: false
  * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: true
* Objective Calls: 1
* Gradient Calls: 1
```

However, the file `log.txt` is 39 lines long and has the following contents:

```
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04000605545445239; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.03999394454554761; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.000024221817809; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 3.9999757781821903; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0000121109089046; χE = 1.0000060554544523; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 1.9999878890910952; χE = 0.9999939445455476; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0000121109089048; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 0.9999878890910953; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.050006358227175; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.049993641772825; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05000605545445239
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.04999394454554761
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04000605545445239; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.03999394454554761; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.000024221817809; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 3.9999757781821903; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0000121109089046; χE = 1.0000060554544523; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 1.9999878890910952; χE = 0.9999939445455476; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0000121109089048; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 0.9999878890910953; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.050006358227175; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.049993641772825; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05000605545445239
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.04999394454554761
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04000605545445239; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.03999394454554761; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.000024221817809; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 3.9999757781821903; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0000121109089046; χE = 1.0000060554544523; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 1.9999878890910952; χE = 0.9999939445455476; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0000121109089048; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 0.9999878890910953; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.050006358227175; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.049993641772825; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05000605545445239
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.04999394454554761
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
    Iteration: ρ = 0.04; χI = 4.0; χS = 2.0; χE = 1.0; λ = 1.05; ν = 0.05
```

What is going on here?

Comment: What did you expect would happen? I mean, how many function evaluations were you expecting? You're approximating the gradient using central finite differences, so it's never going to be just 1 evaluation, and on top of that it's going to evaluate it more than once, because it's a line search based method. Other than that, it's impossible to help you, because you didn't provide a MWE (I cannot run your code and reproduce, because lots of pieces are missing, and some are redundant to the problem you're trying to solve)

Comment: I understand that it's not going to be just one evaluation. My question is why is it calling the function multiple times *at the same input values*, as can be seen in the log file I provided (every time Optim calls the function f, it has to write to log.txt what arguments it called it with, since that is inside the function f - I am fairly certain this works). The results could be cached instead, no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's just very difficult to say without `computeScore`, because I cannot run your example and look into it.

Comment: Okay, I see where the extra calls are coming from. Since we don't seem to initialize the cache in the Fminbox-code, we're hitting this https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/blob/d7b052ea2f5bde0e72ebcbaf6f91effd4632da5a/src/multivariate/solvers/first_order/bfgs.jl#L64 over and over. I've opened an issue https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl/issues/704

Answer (score 0):

1.0e-08 is quite low. Could you try with `g_tol=1.0e-6` to see it it converges?

```
results = optimize(f, lower, upper, initial_x, Fminbox(inner_optimizer), Optim.Options(iterations=0, store_trace=true, show_trace=true, g_tol=1.0e-6))
```